# Why Shoulda executes same test twice

Tags: ruby, testing, shoulda

I'm trying to use Shoulda and context to avoid duplication on my tests. In the following test I would like to expect the following output.

```
"dir created"
"dir removed"
```

but instead I've got

```
"dir created"
"dir removed"
."dir created"
.
Finished tests in 0.001907s, 1048.7677 tests/s, 1048.7677 assertions/s.
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I don't understand why the first test is executed twice?

This is my test code:

```
class FileDirTest < Test::Unit::TestCase 
context "FileDir:" do

setup do
  @fd = FileDir.new
  @myDir = "dir1"
end

context "When dir is create:" do
  setup do
    @fd.create_dir(@myDir)
    p "dir created"
  end
  should "be Dir1" do
    assert_equal true, Dir.exist?(@myDir)
  end
  context "When delete a dir" do
    setup do
      @fd.remove_dir(@myDir)
      p "dir removed"
    end
    should "be removed" do
      assert_equal false, Dir.exist?(@myDir)
    end  
  end
end
```

end
end

Comment: Alright the test are not executed in order they appear on the list. They are executed from the inner test toward the outer one.

"setup"
"dir created"
"dir removed"

then 

"setup"
"dir created"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in any testing framework the setup is run before every test. Since one context is nested in another you see "dir created" twice.

Comment: Alright, it makes sense, but I don't understand why while running the test for "remove dir", asserts ok that means it was deleted, and then it runs the first test again, creating a new dir. When the whole test finishes I can see the dir folder. It shouldn't be there

Comment: If it would be as you are saying I understand it should show this:

    "dir created" -> for the first test. And for the second test would show

    ."dir created" followed by

    "dir removed"

Comment: Tests should not assume any particular order. Ordering tests introduces temporal coupling that makes them brittle. The only order that matters is setup -> run test -> teardown. So what I think you need is a teardown to remove the directory if it's there.